# Replace innerHTML with attribute value for each element with class

Tags: javascript, dom

Please consider this HTML:

```
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 1"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 2"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 3"></a>
```

I want to change it to this:

```
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 1">Product Name 1</a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 2">Product Name 2</a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 3">Product Name 3</a>
```

using JavaScript or jQuery. I can change the first occurrence only with this:

```
var fullName = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].getAttribute("threedots");
document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = fullName;
```

But I need help writing a script that can change all of the occurrences. I have researched foreach and HTMLcollection, but I don't understand them. Can someone point me in the right direction for writing a script that will find each `<a class="title">` and grab the value for its `threedots` attribute and inject it in?

Comment: `threedots` is not a valid attribute. You can use `data-threedots` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of only using the first index of document.getElementsByClassName("title") we can iterate it.

```js
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  
  var title = titles[i];
  
  title.innerHTML = title.getAttribute("threedots");
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 1"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 2"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 3"></a>
```

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply select all the elements by their `[threedots]` attribute and class name, then iterate over them using a simple `for` loop:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.title[threedots]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].textContent = elements[i].getAttribute('threedots');
}
```

Or using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.title[threedots]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
  el.textContent = el.getAttribute('threedots');
});
```

As a side note, since you're only changing text, you can use the [`.textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) rather than `.innerHTML`. In addition, `threedots` isn't a valid attribute. Consider using a `data-*` attribute such as `data-threedots`:

```
<a class="title" data-threedots="Product Name 1"></a>
<a class="title" data-threedots="Product Name 2"></a>
<a class="title" data-threedots="Product Name 3"></a>
```

Then you can access the the property `.dataset.threedots`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.title[data-threedots]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].textContent = elements[i].dataset.threedots;
}
```

Since you mentioned jQuery, you could also use the following:

```
$('.title[data-threedots]').text(function () {
  return $(this).attr('data-threedots');
});
```

Comment: In jQuery you can also use `$(this).data('threedots')`

Answer (score 0):

You select all anchor elements using jQuery and set it.

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).attr('threedots'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 1"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 2"></a>
<a class="title" threedots="Product Name 3"></a>
```